# attempting to get elementt by tag <a> and attribute "class" equals (something) using DOM and VBS

Tags: html, dom, vbscript

I have many tags within an html file and I would like to extract all of the anchor tags with an attribute called 'class' that has a value 'ASCE-url' (which there are many)
They look like this;

```
<A class=ASCE-Url href="../SafetyArgument/N2150158.htm">sub-section</A>
```

How do I write a DOM statement that corresponds to this criteria that extracts a collection of elements that I can then iterate through?

The W3 site has a similar piece of code;

```
txt=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].getAttribute("lang")
```

However, for this to work, it needs to be supplied with a number to go in the square brackets, and for that I need to know the quantity of elements that match the criteria.

I found a piece of javascript that returned the length of the elements returned;

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var ElmLength = elements.length
```

However, VBS doesn't recognise the command Length, is there a VBS alternative to this command?

Answer (score 1):

`Length` works just fine with VBScript. Also `getAttribute("class")` will not work, but `element.className`. Here is example code.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>AAA</title>
  <script type="text/vbscript">
    Sub Window_Onload
        Set objElms = Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
        MsgBox "A.Length: " & objElms.Length
        For Each objElm In objElms
            If objElm.className = "ASCE-Url" Then
                'do what you need here...
                objElm.innerHTML = objElm.innerHTML & " - found"
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

   <a class=ASCE-Url href="#">A</a><br>
   <a class=ASCE-Url href="#">B</a><br>
   <a class=ASCE-XYZ href="#">C</a><br>
   <a class=ASCE-Url href="#">D</a><br>
   <a class=ASCE-Url href="#">E</a><br>

 </body>
</html>
```